# c++ array min max range fraction

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point, comparison

I have an array which fluctuates about between 0.1429 and 0.1428 it doesn't seem to have a real top or bottom though so those numbers could vary.

```
if(myarray[N-1]<myarry[N]){/*always happens*/}
if(myarray[N-1]>myarry[N]){/*never happens*/}
```

the numbers are fractional so there must be smaller fraction in the numbers to show curves on my chart eg: 0.14285216

I am having real trouble with 'greater than' 'smaller than' < > I think it's because i've not got numbers bigger than 1 (myarray[N-1] shows 0 always)

can I do something to my data like increase the range or use another method to '<>'?

really stuck

Comment: How does an array "fluctuate about between 0.1429 and 0.1428" or not "have a real top or bottom"?  And I'm not sure you've really asked a question here.  What does you mean by "do something to [your] data like increase the range"?  What are you wanting here?  Can you clarify this question?

Comment: Maybe also show us a *representative* sample of the numbers you're trying to process?

Comment: you are using a floating point data type right?

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from, are they from an input file, or from a calculation.  If from an input file, have you printed the numbers post file read to make sure they are coming in properly?  Perhaps you should try doubles instead of floats also.

Comment: *i've not got numbers bigger than 1 (myarray[N-1] shows 0 always* This sounds exactly like the effects of integer truncation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you want to do is display the numbers in an array so as to see the differences between them?  The reason for your always/never situation is that the array is sorted, which is probably a good thing.  Anyway, to display a greater number of digits, you can use format specifiers, such as

```
printf ("my ith number: %.10f", myarray[i]);
```

This will give you `myarray[i]` with 10 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

what is:

myarray versus myarry (missing the a between the second r and the y)

Direct from your code given above:

```
if(myarray[N-1]<myarry[N]){/*always happens*/}
if(myarray[N-1]>myarry[N]){/*never happens*/}
```

Shouldnt it be:

```
if(myarray[N-1]<myarray[N]){/*always happens*/}
if(myarray[N-1]>myarray[N]){/*never happens*/}
```

Also I hope you arent ever using N = 0 as an input to this set of if statements.

Comment: myarry is a spelling mistake sorry i miss spelled it here not in my original code, in my original i call it a[] (this way i can't miss spell :P)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to multiply all numbers by 7 and subtract 1 - that will make the relative differences larger.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a good idea...

Comment: This answer is not worse than the question!

Comment: Haha well that is very true!  I love these kinds of questions though, they make me feel better on bad days because I know my bad days aren't all that bad